# Is it possible to modify a page's CSS using jQuery (not element but global css)

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to modify a page's CSS using jQuery (not element but global css)?

For example I have a CSS entery of:

```
.page.left {
    top: -100%;
}
```

in my main stylesheet and I would like to modify it in runtime to top: -50%
is it possible? again, it may be that this style may or may not been applied to any elements...

??

Thanks,

Sean.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do what you're asking for:

```
$('.page.left').css('top', '-50%');
```

It will find all (if any) elements on the page with both classes `page` and `left` and apply the new `top` style to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same css selector to set the rules for these elements using jquery.

Example CSS rule:

```
.page.left {
  top: -100%;
}
```

In Jquery it would be:

```
$(".page.left").css("top","-100%");
```

but this will change only on the page where above line is executed.